# How to access Physical memory from user space?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a custom board with physical memory of 6GB.I have constraint in mapping the physical memory through mmap and accessing it from user space.when i map the physical memory of 1GB,mmap doesn't return any error but i am not able to write beyond 200 MB.

Can anyone guide me on how to access the physical memory and perform memory test of 1 GB from user space.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040303/accessing-physical-address-from-user-space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [memtester](http://pyropus.ca/software/memtester/), it may already do what you want, and if not, the source code should be a reasonable starting point.